# Abort ajax request in a promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, cancellation

I'm building a form validation and to learn promises I decided to implement asynchronous validation functions using promise pattern:

```
var validateAjax = function(value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax('data.json', {data: {value: value}}).success(function(data, status, xhr) {
            if (data.valid) {
                resolve(xhr)
            }
            else {
                reject(data.message)
            }
        }).error(function(xhr, textStatus) {
            reject(textStatus)
        })
    })
}

//...
var validators = [validateAjax];
$('body').delegate('.validate', 'keyup', function() {
    var value = $('#the-input').val();
    var results = validators.map(function(validator) {
        return validator(input)
    });

    var allResolved = Promise.all(results).then(function() {
        //...
    }).catch(function() {
        //...
    })
});
```

This seems to be working fine, the input is validated as user types (the code is simplified not to be too long, for example timeout after the keyup is missing and so on).

Now I'm wondering how to kill the ajax request if the validation from the previous keyup event is still in progress. Is it somehow possible to detect in which state the promise is and possibly reject the promise from outside?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Promise cancellation is currently under specification, there is no built in way to do this yet (it's coming though). We can implement it ourselves:

```
var validateAjax = function(value) {
    // remove explicit construction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743
    var xhr = $.ajax('data.json', {data: {value: value}}); 
    var promise = Promise.resolve(xhr).then(function(data){
         if(!data.isValid) throw new Error(data.message); // throw errors
         return data;
    });
    promise.abort = function(){
       xhr.abort();
    };
    return promise;
}
```

Now, we can kill the validateAjax calls by calling `abort` on the promise:

```
var p = validateAjax("..."); // make request
p.abort(); // abort it;
```

Comment: Great, I get it, thanks for your answer. Anyway regarding the removal of explicit construction - the xhr still needs to be returned from the validateAjax function, right?

Comment: your validateAjax returns undefined - is there a line missing?

Comment: @LukasKral - I think the var `promise` would need to be returned, as it has the `.abort` function - but I didn't write the code, so I can only speculate

Comment: This is a great idea.  Unfortunately, the function will get lost in the chain. so var p = validateAjax(...).then(..);  p.abort();  // no such function

Comment: Right, it doesn't chain.

Comment: There's an unexpected ')' at the end of assigning to promise.abort.

Comment: I used a whole day to figure out that this does not work when chaining `then()` on the same line. Do this: var `p = validateAjax(); p.then(function() {//do stuff})`. Now `p.abort()` is available.

Comment: This answer is ancient don't do this instead use AbortSignal or Symbol.dispose